# Make a vbox as tall as it needs to be up to the max-height

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have a vbox with a description inside it. It has a style of overflow:auto. If I set no height on the vbox, it is too short and cuts of the content with a scroll bar. It becomes about 50px where 150px is needed to show all. If I set an explicit height, it becomes that height, but I don't want to set an explicit height. If I set a max-height, it is still too short and cuts of the content with a scroll bar.

I want it to not cut off anything, unless the height would exceed a max height of 400px. How can this be done?

**This is the markup:**

```
<vbox flex="1" align="center">
   <image src='chrome://dfsdf/skin/sdf.svg' width='100px' />
   <label class="header" value="An Exception Has Occurred"/>
   <!-- the following should be as tall as needed as with no scroll bars long as it is less than 200px, if longer than 200px, make it 200 and add scroll bars -->
   <vbox flex="1" class="ErrorMessageWrapper">
      <description id="ExceptionDescription">
         The exception should appear here.
      </description>
   </vbox>
   <label value="Trace"/>
   <!-- the following should be as tall as needed as with no scroll bars long as it is less than 400px, if longer than 400px, make it 400 and add scroll bars -->
   <vbox flex="1" class="ErrorMessageWrapper">
      <description id="ExceptionTrace">
         The exception trace should appear here.
      </description>
   </vbox>
   <hbox  class="FieldWrapper" pack="right" align="right" flex="0">                   
         <button label="Try Again" class="Button" oncommand="RetryConnection();" />
   </hbox>
</vbox>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ErrorMessageWrapper{
   border:1px solid #070707;
   background:#141414;
   padding:20px;
   padding-bottom:11px;
   margin-bottom:20px;
   width:700px;
   overflow:auto;
   max-height:400px; /* Does nothing! */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

XUL does not quite behave the same as HTML. I'm not aware of any way to achieve the same effect without resorting to some Javascript trickery, something along the lines of:

```
addEventListener("load", function() {
    // After the text has been set...
    let box = document.getElementById("ExceptionTraceWrapper");
    if (box.boxObject.height > 400) {
        box.style.height = "400px";
        box.style.overflow = "auto";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `min-height:200px;`? It will force the element to have at-least 200px size even if content inside is smaller.